# Split words from CamelCase string

Tags: regex, string, matlab, strtok

I have a string

```
string =  'one Two9three four_Five 67SixSevenEightNine';
```

I need to split it into the words:

```
'one' 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' 'six' 'seven' 'eight' 'nine'
```

I managed to separate all except the CamelCase, when the lowercase letter is followed by uppercase:

```
while ~isempty(string)
        [str,string] = ...
           strtok(string, ...
                  [' ~@$/#.-:&*+=[]?!(){},''">_<;%' char(9) char(10) char(13) '0-9']);
       str = regexprep(str, '[0-9]','');
end
```

I also can get the index of the pattern, but only if I knew how to insert space or some character between, then I could use the code above once again to split into words:

```
pattern = '[a-z][A-Z]+';
[pat,idx]=regexp(str, pattern,'match');
```

any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not replace the camelCase before you do your other processing?

```
newstring = regexprep(string, '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2');

while ~isempty(newstring)
...
```